# how to get text of when click on specific radio using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html

I am having difficulty to figure it out how to get only text of question 2 and question 4 when I click on radio button. For example, If I click on Java in question 2 and Python in Question 4 then the result should be display in console Java and Python.Can anyone help me please? I am badly stuck in this.I would appreciate your help.

```js
function answers() {


  var q = document.querySelectorAll('.question');
  [...q].forEach(c => {

    if (c.checked) {
      console.log(c);
    }
  })



}
```

```html
<label>Question 1</label>
<input type="radio" id='questiona' class="question" name="question" value="1"><label for="questiona">a) HTML</label>
<input type="radio" id='questionb' class="question" name="question" value="2"><label for="questionb">b) HTML5</label>
<input type="radio" id='questionc' class="question" name="question" value="3"><label for="questionc">c) XHTML</label>
<br/>
<label>Question 2</label>
<input type="radio" id='question2a' class="question" name="question2" value="1"><label for="question2a">a) Java</label>
<input type="radio" id='question2b' class="question" name="question2" value="2"><label for="question2b">b) CSS</label>
<input type="radio" id='question2c' class="question" name="question2" value="3"><label for="question2c">c) JavaScript</label>
<br/>
<label>Question 3</label>
<input type="radio" id='question3a' class="question" name="question3" value="1">a)PASCAL</label>
<input type="radio" id='question3b' class="question" name="question3" value="2">b) COBOL</label>
<input type="radio" id='question2c' class="question" name="question3" value="3">c) Assembly</label>
<br/>
<label>Question 4</label>
<input type="radio" id='question4a' class="question" name="question4" value="1"><label for="question4a">a) Python</label>
<input type="radio" id='question4b' class="question" name="question4" value="2"><label for="question4b">b) C#</label>
<input type="radio" id='question4c' class="question" name="question4" value="3"><label for="question4c">c) Typscript</label>
<br/>
<a href="#" onclick="answers()">Submit</a>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change console.log from

```
console.log(c);
```

to:

```
console.log(c.nextElementSibling.innerText);
```

.nextElementSibling will look for next element (in this case label)

and next function .innerText will get text in this label.

Answer (score 1):

First, I would set the VALUE to what you want to show up instead of 1,2,3.

Second, you were also most there, change

`console.log(c);`

to

`console.log(c.value);`

Also you can just loop through :checked radio instead of all of them.

```js
function answers() {


  var q = document.querySelectorAll('.question:checked');
  [...q].forEach(c => {

      console.log(c.value);
  })



}
```

```html
<label>Question 1</label>
<input type="radio" id='questiona' class="question" name="question" value="HTML"><label for="questiona">a) HTML</label>
<input type="radio" id='questionb' class="question" name="question" value="HTML5"><label for="questionb">b) HTML5</label>
<input type="radio" id='questionc' class="question" name="question" value="XHTML"><label for="questionc">c) XHTML</label>
<br/>
<label>Question 2</label>
<input type="radio" id='question2a' class="question" name="question2" value="Java"><label for="question2a">a) Java</label>
<input type="radio" id='question2b' class="question" name="question2" value="CSS"><label for="question2b">b) CSS</label>
<input type="radio" id='question2c' class="question" name="question2" value="JavaScript"><label for="question2c">c) JavaScript</label>
<br/>
<label>Question 3</label>
<input type="radio" id='question3a' class="question" name="question3" value="PASCAL">a)PASCAL</label>
<input type="radio" id='question3b' class="question" name="question3" value="COBOL">b) COBOL</label>
<input type="radio" id='question2c' class="question" name="question3" value="Assembly">c) Assembly</label>
<br/>
<label>Question 4</label>
<input type="radio" id='question4a' class="question" name="question4" value="Python"><label for="question4a">a) Python</label>
<input type="radio" id='question4b' class="question" name="question4" value="C#"><label for="question4b">b) C#</label>
<input type="radio" id='question4c' class="question" name="question4" value="Typscript"><label for="question4c">c) Typscript</label>
<br/>
<a href="#" onclick="answers()">Submit</a>
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. The text is successfully displaying in console but as I mentioned in my description above, I want to display the text of only question 2 and question4 using same code that u edited in ur answer. For example, For example, If I click on Java in question 2 and Python in Question 4 then the result should be display in console Java and Python

Answer (score 1):

- use the `:checked` selector to get the checked ones
- [NodeList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList/forEach) already provides the `.forEach()` by default, no need to destructure the Array `[...]`
- Use [`Element.addEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) instead of inline JavaScript
- No need for that myriad of IDs, simply wrap your Input Element inside `<label>`
- Don't use `<label>` without referencing it to a FormAction Element (using `for` or encompassing a FormAction Element). `<label>` has no specific semantic value on it's own.
- Finally to get the `<label>` text use [`.closest("label")`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/closest) method - from the input Element

```js
const answers = (evt) => {
  evt.preventDefault(); // Prevent browser default action
  
  const ELS_qChecked = document.querySelectorAll('.question:checked');
  ELS_qChecked.forEach(EL => {
    const EL_label = EL.closest("label");
    const text = EL_label.textContent;
    console.log(EL.name +' '+ EL.value +' '+ text);
  });
}


const EL_submitBtn = document.querySelector("#submit");
EL_submitBtn.addEventListener("click", answers);
```

```html
<div>Question 1</div>
<label><input type="radio" class="question" name="question1" value="1">a) HTML</label>
<label><input type="radio" class="question" name="question1" value="2">b) HTML5</label>
<label><input type="radio" class="question" name="question1" value="3">c) XHTML</label>
<br>
<div>Question 2</div>
<label><input type="radio" class="question" name="question2" value="1">a) Java</label>
<label><input type="radio" class="question" name="question2" value="2">b) CSS</label>
<label><input type="radio" class="question" name="question2" value="3">c) JavaScript</label>
<br>
<div>Question 3</div>
<label><input type="radio" class="question" name="question3" value="1">a) PASCAL</label>
<label><input type="radio" class="question" name="question3" value="2">b) COBOL</label>
<label><input type="radio" class="question" name="question3" value="3">c) Assembly</label>
<br>
<div>Question 4</div>
<label><input type="radio" class="question" name="question4" value="1">a) Python</label>
<label><input type="radio" class="question" name="question4" value="2">b) C#</label>
<label><input type="radio" class="question" name="question4" value="3">c) Typscript</label>
<br>

<a href="#" id="submit">Submit</a>
```

Comment: Thanks for your response.but I want to display text not value. like If I select Java in question 2 then Java must display on console not value. Can u please help me out?

Comment: @kodder360 Sure, Thanks to the `<label>` being now wrappers - it's possible and easy. See the Edit above.

Comment: Thanks so much for ur response, The text is successfully displaying in console but as I mentioned in my description above, I want to display the text of only question 2 and question4 . For example, For example, If I click on Java in question 2 and Python in Question 4 then the result should be display in console Java and Python

Comment: because the project I am working on, I have 19 questions but I want to display text only 7 question which user has selected not all the selected results of 19. I would really appreciate ur help.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```js
function answers() {


  var q = document.querySelectorAll('.question:checked+label');
  [...q].forEach(c => {
 
      console.log(c.innerHTML);
 
  })



}
```

```html
<label>Question 1</label>
<input type="radio" id='questiona' class="question" name="question" value="1"><label for="questiona">a) HTML</label>
<input type="radio" id='questionb' class="question" name="question" value="2"><label for="questionb">b) HTML5</label>
<input type="radio" id='questionc' class="question" name="question" value="3"><label for="questionc">c) XHTML</label>
<br/>
<label>Question 2</label>
<input type="radio" id='question2a' class="question" name="question2" value="1"><label for="question2a">a) Java</label>
<input type="radio" id='question2b' class="question" name="question2" value="2"><label for="question2b">b) CSS</label>
<input type="radio" id='question2c' class="question" name="question2" value="3"><label for="question2c">c) JavaScript</label>
<br/>
<label>Question 3</label>
<input type="radio" id='question3a' class="question" name="question3" value="1">a)PASCAL</label>
<input type="radio" id='question3b' class="question" name="question3" value="2">b) COBOL</label>
<input type="radio" id='question2c' class="question" name="question3" value="3">c) Assembly</label>
<br/>
<label>Question 4</label>
<input type="radio" id='question4a' class="question" name="question4" value="1"><label for="question4a">a) Python</label>
<input type="radio" id='question4b' class="question" name="question4" value="2"><label for="question4b">b) C#</label>
<input type="radio" id='question4c' class="question" name="question4" value="3"><label for="question4c">c) Typscript</label>
<br/>
<a href="#" onclick="answers()">Submit</a>
```

Comment: A uniform HTML structure should be preferred as there could dynamic data. Think about the machine, how would it identify if it for a particular action to be taken?